# NSTokenField for iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, nstokenfield

I'm looking for a custom implementation of a NSTokenField for iOS just like in Mail App. Something like this: https://github.com/zoonooz/ZFTokenField/blob/master/Classes/ZFTokenField.m

It would be awesome if it was already bindable for MvvmCross. ;)

Does any one know any implementation?

I would add this to my search text field, would that be possible? Or I would have to create my own UISearchBar that overrides the textfield with my new NSTokenField?

Thanks in regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recently struggle with similar problem, tags/tokens in searchBar. I decided to use `TLTagsControl`. It works great in navigation bar. I had some layout issues with other ones including your ZFTokenField, but this works great. I edited this code to allow inserting images in tags. If you want that to, let me know, I post my code on GitHub.

Unfortunelty you can't use it with UISearchBar, you need simply add TLTagsControl as titleView in navigationBar.
Hope that helps.

[TLTagsControl](https://github.com/ali312/TLTagsControl)